# Javascript [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   $('.buttons').click(function actionInButton(act){
if($(this).css('opacity') != 0.5) {
    $('.Yes').attr('value', (act + " " + $(this).attr("alt")));
    hero = this;
}
    });        
 actionInButton("Ban");
```

Выдает "[object Object] %правильно%"
В чем ошибка?

Comment: Вы бы объяснили поподробнее, что вы хотите сделать(или что вы ожидаете) и что у вас не получается, из вашего вопроса это совершенно не ясно.

Comment: По клику на одну из кнопок с классом ".buttons", кнопка ".Yes" должна присвоиться значение "act(это слово, передаваемое в функции) + alt из нажатой кнопки(".buttons")"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть на [документацию](https://api.jquery.com/click/) то можно заметить что в функцию `click` передается функция обработчик, которая будет вызвана при нажатии на кнопку. Параметр который будет передан в эту функцию это [Event](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Event).

Вы же пытаетесь задать функцию обработчик присвоив ей имя `actionInButton` и потом вызвать её с параметром `Ban`. Если вкратце, то это так не работает. Вам надо либо в каждую кнопку на которую навешивается этот обработчик задать параметр и брать его как вы берете атрибут `alt`. Либо использовать другой подход, какой именно сказать трудно не зная всех требований.

Судя по той ошибке которую вы допускаете, вы не совсем понимает основные принципы JS, в частности замыкания и то как работают обработчики разных событий, на вашем месте я бы сначала заполнил эти пробелы. Думаю можно начать с этих ресурсов [ответ на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work), [курс на w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) и [документация на developer mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $('.buttons').click(function actionInButton(act){
> ```

Здесь `this` - это event. Ты складываешь с объектом.

> ```
> actionInButton("Ban");
> ```

А это вообще ошибка - такой функции нет.

Comment: А не подскажешь, пожалуйста, как реализовать это тогда?
Бью голову и не получается никак(

Comment: @gmate, b откуда я должен знать, что ты хочешь реализовать?